# PHP : Move all CSS code from body to head tag

Tags: php, regex

I have site like this for example , I am trying to put all those style tags in body tag inside head tag.

```
    <html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
<nav>navbar</nav>
    <div>bla ba ... lots of html contents</div>

    <style>
    .h1
    {
    color:red;
    }
    </style>
    <div>bla ba ... lots of html contents</div>
    <style>
    .h2
    {
    green;
    }
    </style>

<footer>
footer
</footer>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I wanted to do in php , I tried following code.But will it slow my page ? Is there any other alternative to this ?

```
$output = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

$output = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $output);

preg_match_all('/<style>(.*?)<\/style>/s', $output, $mat);
$output = preg_replace('/<style>(.*?)<\/style>/s', '', $output);

foreach($mat[0] as $headsty)
{
$output = str_replace("</head>",$headsty."</head>",$output);
}

echo $output;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex is not the right tool for this. It will become more difficult to get right as your code complexity increases. Instead you should use the PHP::Dom classes. You can use that to scan the HTML and pull out the `<style>` elements and then rewrite them to the `<head>` element like so...

```
$html = <<<EOF
    <html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
    <nav>navbar</nav>
    <div>bla ba ... lots of html contents</div>

    <style>
    .h1
    {
    color:red;
    }
    </style>
    <div>bla ba ... lots of html contents</div>
    <style>
    .h2
    {
    green;
    }
    </style>

    <footer>
        footer
    </footer>
    </body>
    </html>
EOF;

// Suppress warnings about invalid elements
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);

$styles = $dom->getElementsByTagName('style');

$head = $dom->getElementsByTagName('head')->item(0);
foreach ($styles as $style) {
    $head->appendChild($style);
}

echo "<pre>" . htmlentities( $dom->saveHTML() ) . "</pre>";
```

Comment: I get errors like Tag nav invalid in Entity, tag footer invalid

Comment: You should post the code that is causing you errors. The code provided works for the sample you gave... http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/pi8h-2wi2

Comment: I have edited the code in my question , please check

Comment: @Vishnu Those errors are due to limitations of PHP::Dom. It only uses HTML4 standards and HTML5 allows for those tags. Applying `libxml_use_internal_errors(true);` will suppress those errors for you. I have updated my example to show how it is used.